# Install perl 5.10.1 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: perl

I am trying to install an old version of perl (5.10.1) since it is a dependency for software I want to use ([and newer versions do not work](https://github.com/WGLab/GenGen/issues/6)). I downloaded the source from https://www.cpan.org/src/README.html. Following their instructions:

```
 ./Configure -des -Dprefix=$HOME/localperl
 make
 make test
 make install
```

However, `make` fails with:

```
cc -L/usr/local/lib -o miniperl \
    `echo  gv.o toke.o perly.o op.o pad.o regcomp.o dump.o util.o mg.o reentr.o hv.o av.o perl.o run.o pp_hot.o sv.o pp.o scope.o pp_ctl.o pp_sys.o doop.o doio.o regexec.o utf8.o taint.o deb.o universal.o xsutils.o globals.o perlio.o perlapi.o numeric.o mathoms.o locale.o pp_pack.o pp_sort.o  | sed 's/ op.o / /'` \
    miniperlmain.o opmini.o 
pp.o: In function `Perl_pp_pow':
pp.c:(.text+0x2d84): undefined reference to `pow'
pp.o: In function `Perl_pp_modulo':
pp.c:(.text+0x3b80): undefined reference to `fmod'
pp.o: In function `Perl_pp_atan2':
pp.c:(.text+0x8884): undefined reference to `atan2'
pp.o: In function `Perl_pp_sin':
pp.c:(.text+0x8978): undefined reference to `sqrt'
pp.c:(.text+0x8a23): undefined reference to `log'
pp.c:(.text+0x8a4e): undefined reference to `cos'
pp.c:(.text+0x8afb): undefined reference to `sin'
pp.c:(.text+0x8b13): undefined reference to `exp'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:313: recipe for target 'miniperl' failed
make: *** [miniperl] Error 1
```

I have tried installing miniperl (whatever that is) with `apt install libcpan-mini-perl`, but this made no difference. [This question mentions this is a problem with the math library](https://serverfault.com/questions/761966/building-old-perl-from-source-how-to-add-math-library), but I don't see how to apply this solution in this context. I guess one has to edit the `makefile` somewhere, but where?

Comment: [Devel::PatchPerl](http://p3rl.org/Devel::PatchPerl) can often help building older versions of Perl. Fixing the software instead sounds like the way forward, though.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy the command, and add the `-lm` at last, like:

```
cc -L/usr/local/lib -o miniperl \
    `echo  gv.o toke.o perly.o op.o pad.o regcomp.o dump.o util.o mg.o reentr.o hv.o av.o perl.o run.o pp_hot.o sv.o pp.o scope.o pp_ctl.o pp_sys.o doop.o doio.o regexec.o utf8.o taint.o deb.o universal.o xsutils.o globals.o perlio.o perlapi.o numeric.o mathoms.o locale.o pp_pack.o pp_sort.o  | sed 's/ op.o / /'` \
    miniperlmain.o opmini.o -lm
```

then re-run the `make`, the `make` program will thought the dependecy is solved and will continue to compile.

Comment: I get a long list like `cc: error: gv.o: No such file or directory`.